# Filtering Fast User Touch Input

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch

I am coding an app in sprite-kit and swift where when you touch the screen a sprite(the player) throws a projectile at another sprite moving towards it. If the player hits the other sprite then the projectile and the sprite disappear. A problem with the game is that if the player rapidly touches the screen he can easily run up his score in the game. How can I make the code only recognize that the screen is being touched every let's say .3 seconds?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. See: [How do I Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In SpriteKit/GameplayKit games, most of your code is running inside a game loop where you are constantly being passed the current time.  That's what this function in an SKScene is:

```
override public func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
}
```

In here it's common to keep track of time and enable/disable things. To keep it simple:

1. Add the following vars

   ```
   var firingEnabled = true
   var enableFiringAtTime: TimeInterval = 0
   var currentTime: TimeInterval = 0
   ```
2. When they fire, add this code

   ```
   if firingEnabled {
       firingEnabled = false
       enableFiringAtTime = self.currentTime + 0.3
       // your fire code here
   }
   ```
3. And in the update override

   ```
   self.currentTime = currentTime
   if currentTime > enableFiringAtTime {
       firingEnabled = true
   }
   ```